# How do you make a list of random numbers

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, random, numbers

I'm working with python to create a game that the computer will pick numbers from 1 to 10 and the player can choose which numbers they want to keep or delete..The sum of the random numbers must add up to 21 and the player has only 10 tries.What would be the code I use to create the list of random numbers to equal 21 and let the player delete numbers they want.Thank you!!!

I've already started on some of it..The program I use Python 2.7.5 on Mac...

```
import random
import time

name = raw_input("Hello, What's your name?")
print "Welcome," ,name, "Time to play Catch 21!"
time.sleep(1)

tries = 0
tries_remaining = 10
while tries < 10:
          tries += 1
          tries_remaining -= 1

from time import sleep
total = 0

for i in range(10):
    total = total + random()

print total

while True:
    print "Your card is"
    values = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    print(random.randint(1,10))
    print"Do you want to keep or delete this card?"
    card = raw_input("K = Keep.  D = Delete. ")
    from time import sleep
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please take the time to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [what can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  As it is written your code makes absolutely no sense, you use `time.sleep()` but never `import time`, you try to call the module `random()` which is invalid, and you never do anything with the number 21, nor anything with the `card` or `values` variables...

Comment: I understand that the code is only partially done but please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that represents the issue you are facing without a large amount of irrelevant and unused noise.

Comment: How many times will you `import time` and `sleep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of random values, just call `random.randint` and `append` the result to a list. A contrived example:

```
import random
values = []  # list to hold accepted values
for _ in range(10):  # aka "do the following ten times"
    card_value = random.randint(1,10)  # draw a number
    values.append(card_value)  # store it on the list
    # or just 'values.append(random.randint(1,10))'
# values is now something like [1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 10, 8, 5, 9, 10]
```

Now, you want to do this conditionally. So, let's add player interaction:

```
import random
values = []  # list to hold accepted values
# give the player 10 tries
for _ in range(10):  # aka "do the following ten times"
    card_value = random.randint(1, 10)  # pick a card and remember it, we need it several times
    print("Draw: %2d. Do you want to keep or delete this card?" % card_value)  # show card
    keep_delete = raw_input("K = Keep.  D = Delete.")
    if keep_delete == "K":  # wants to keep the card...
      values.append(card_value)  # ...so we store it on the list
      print("Added %2d." % card_value)
    else:  # let's ignore checking ALL variants of wrong input in this example
      print("Discarded %2d." % card_value)
    print("Current sum: %2d" % sum(values))  # sum just sums up all values in values

# At this point, the player has all his/her cards
# check whether player won
if sum(values) == 21:
   print("You are winner!!!")
else:
   print("You lost :(")
```

There's some more flow control you can do, e.g. checking inside the loop whether `sum(values) > 21` and then using `break` to exit prematurely.

Also, if you want to have a fixed number of each card, you have to actually limit what cards are dealt. The following would work:

```
import random
available_values = list(range(1, 11))  # all integers from 1 to 10
accepted_values = []  # list to hold accepted values
while available_values:  # aka "do the following as long as we have cards"
    card_value = available_values.pop(random.randint(len(available_values)))  # pop removes the chosen card
    values.append(card_value)  # store it on the list
# values is now something like [1, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 5, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

So i have fix your code like this:

```
import random
import time
# name = raw_input("Hello, What's your name?")
# changed this to this:
name = raw_input("Hello, What's your name? ")
print "Welcome," ,name, "Time to play Catch 21!"
time.sleep(1)
tries = 0
# tries_remaining = 10
# you don't need this it's enough to have tries, and tries_remaining can
# be calculated easily at any time, just use 10-tries instead

# you have while loop, than for loop and then again while loop,
# but you need to have only one loop and i think it's best to
# use while loop
'''
while tries < 10:
          tries += 1
          tries_remaining -= 1
from time import sleep
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    total = total + random()
print total
while True:
    print "Your card is"
    values = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    print(random.randint(1,10))
    print"Do you want to keep or delete this card?"
    card = raw_input("K = Keep.  D = Delete. ")
    from time import sleep
    time.sleep(1)
'''
# you need to define total before while loop
total = 0
# so I'll copy first and second row
while tries < 10:
    tries += 1
# like I said you don't need tries_remaining
# also you don't need from time import sleep because you 
# already have import time
#       by the way when you use:
#           import time     then you need to use:       time.sleep(2)
#       but when you use:
#           from time import sleep      then you need to use:      sleep(2) 
#       instead of 2 you can use any other number of second
# so total is already defined and now you have to randomize card
# you need to save that value because you will need it later
    card = random.randint(1,10)
# same way of importing time applies to importing any module
# so you can use import random or from random import randint
# now you print card and total
    print "Your card is", str(card) + ", you have", total, "in total"
# you ask user to keep it or delete it
    print"Do you want to keep or delete this card?"
    answer = raw_input("K = Keep.  D = Delete. ")
# what you are missing in your code is to check what is answer
# and to do what user have chosen
    if answer == "K":
        # you need to add card to total
        total += card
# if answer is "D" you don't have to do anything
# at the end we can use time.sleep, although I think there is no purpose of it
    time.sleep(1)

# at the end we can print the score (total)
print "End of game, you have", total, "in total."
```

and here is code without comments:

```
import random
import time
name = raw_input("Hello, What's your name? ")
print "Welcome," ,name, "Time to play Catch 21!"
time.sleep(1)
tries = 0
total = 0
while tries < 10:
    tries += 1
    card = random.randint(1,10)
    print "Your card is", str(card) + ", you have", total, "in total"
    print"Do you want to keep or delete this card?"
    answer = raw_input("K = Keep.  D = Delete. ")
    if answer == "K":
        total += card
    time.sleep(1)
print "End of game, you have", total, "in total."
```